# Trying to make a TCPDF generated PDF file automatically print to letterhead tray

Tags: pdf, printing, tcpdf, tray

I am generating invoices with TCPDF and everything is working fine. The pdf files need to be printed onto letterhead paper. I couldn't find any information on this, but is it possible to set a "letterhead" paper type in the pdf document so that when printed it will automatically choose the tray with letterhead paper (of course, the printer has the ability to set what kind of paper is in which tray)?

Comment: Printing to different trays is not an easy problem because print drivers vary based on hardware.  As far as I know, there is no way to specify a tray in a PDF, let alone a letterhead paper tray.

Comment: I thought there might be a variable that could be set in a pdf that says it should be printed on letterhead (like there is for paper format and orientation) and then when you print if from the pc it would automatically select letterhead type of paper.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the examples provided on the TCPDF website, there seems to be a few things there about page preferences and a possible solution to your tray problem.

Have a look at:

[Print Preferences](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_029.phps)

and

[Advanced Page Settings](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_060.phps)

Seems pretty interesting, looks like there maybe some built in functions that will automatically choose the tray based on the size of the PDF.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, but i had already foud one of those examples and it doesn't have any options for paper type, just paper size. thanks, anyway.